# Snapping Bézier handles on Blender 3.1

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, snapping

Previously, in Blender 2.83, it was possible to snap Bézier handles to each other with "Snap to vertex".

When I tried to do this in Blender 3.1, not only was I unable to do it, but it also showed weird behaviour:

[image: 2.83 and 3.1 comparison]

Is this a bug?
If so, should I report it in the bug tracker? I have never done it, and I'm afraid to do it wrong.

Comment: I think this is actually correcting a "bug" from a previous version. Threoretically, it works as expeted now. A curve handle control point is not really a "vertex" so snapping to those is probably not correct, when Vertex Snapping is enabled. Although i do find it strange that it's "snapping" in mid-air when moving the handless in empty space. Maybe someone else can chime in with their thoughts.

Comment: looks like a bug to me.  I can reproduce the behavior in 3.1.2.

Comment: Yeah the whole thing is very buggy, it seems it still takes the control point handles in account when calculating the vertices to snap to. Using median interpolation is a mess since moving the control point changes the point it can snap to.

Comment: Might be related to this currently open [issue](https://developer.blender.org/T97401)